# SpringMVC form:options items attribute: what exactly is it expecting?

Tags: spring-mvc, jstl

I'm still new to SpringMVC (and jstl for that matter).  I'm trying to populate options in a select from a list of objects.  I've found a way to do it using c:forEach, but I keep thinking there HAS to be a way to make the form:options method work.

I've browsed around, and about the closest thing I can find to official documentation on the items attribute is here >> http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/spring-form.tld.html#spring-form.tld.options

It says the items attribute is for

> "The Collection, Map or array of objects used to generate the inner 'option' tags"

My confusion is what kind of Collection, Map, or array of objects it's looking for.  What format do they need to be in?  Is it looking for a Collection or array of type String specifically?  Can I use

```
List<MyObject>
```

and if so, what would MyObject have to have in it in order for this to be valid (i.e. methods, variables)?

Currently, when I try to use MyObject, I get an exception that says -

> ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type com.example.MyObject to type java.lang.String

Do I need to make a converter?  Where would that go?  How would that work?  I've googled that error message and haven't really turned up anything specific to what I'm trying to do...  (Most are results about Roo)

the MyObject class looks like this:

```
public class MyObject{
    private String company;
    private Customer customer;
    private Address customerAddress;

    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    public Address getCustomerAddress() {
        return customerAddress;
    }

    public void setCustomerAddress(Address customerAddress) {
        this.customerAddress = customerAddress;
    }
}
```

and I'm trying to use it as such:

```
<form:select path="myObjectList">
    <form:option value="0"/>
    <form:options items="myObjectList" /> 
</form:select>
```

Does anyone know specifically what is incorrect about this method?  Or, should I be using a

```
List<String>
```

to accomplish what I'm doing?

**EDIT** here's the stack trace >> http://pastebin.com/2c5XBCmG

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [Spring Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html) says this about the `items` attribute of the `form:options` tag:

> The items attribute is typically populated with a collection or array
>   of item objects. itemValue and itemLabel simply refer to bean
>   properties of those item objects, if specified; otherwise, the item
>   objects themselves will be stringified. Alternatively, you may specify
>   a Map of items, in which case the map keys are interpreted as option
>   values and the map values correspond to option labels. If itemValue
>   and/or itemLabel happen to be specified as well, the item value
>   property will apply to the map key and the item label property will
>   apply to the map value.

In a nutshell, if you need to use a List of your Custom Beans as the items attribute you need to use also the `itemValue` and `itemLabel` attributes. Personally, I'll prefer using Maps -`LinkedHashMap` instances speciffically- for populating my select tags, but that's a matter of taste.

Adapting an example from the Spring Documentation, your code should look like this:

```
 <form:select path="commandAttribute">
      <form:option value="-" label="--Please Select"/>
      <form:options items="${countryList}" itemValue="company" itemLabel="company"/>
 </form:select>
```

I'm using the `company` attribute as both `itemValue` and `itemLabel`, but you're free to choose the attributes that fit your requirements.

Comment: Alright, so what I need is an itemValue and an itemLabel.  and those I can get from the object list i have sent in, right?

so in my case:  <form:options items="${myObjectList}" itemValue="company" itemLabel="customer.name" />

company is a String within the MyObject class, and name is a String within the Customer class... 

this should work in theory, but... I still keep getting that error...

Comment: I mentioned it in the original question, the ConverterNotFoundException.  I'll add the full stack trace to the original post, if that would be helpful.  I'll also paste it here >> http://pastebin.com/2c5XBCmG

Comment: I'm suspecting the issue comes from the path attribute. Every time I used, is related to an String attribute of the command. Can you try it?

Comment: That is indeed what was causing the error.  I was setting the path to be the actual list of objects rather than to a string.  This resolves the exception I was getting, but now I'm trying to figure out why it won't populate the options with anything.  Should I move this to another question, or is it fine here?  I'm not getting any more errors, and I can verify that the list has data in it...  but nothing populates.  I only have what's in the first manually-placed option - form:option value="0"/>

Comment: Nevermind... I found the issue there as well.  apparently, for whatever reason, I have to qualify the list by telling it what object it's coming from, even though I already set that in the commandName attribute in the declaration of the form.  That's rather interesting actually... all of the other form elements I have don't require that qualification for their paths... why would this one?  Am I correct in this statement, or should the items attribute inherit the qualifying commandName like all the other form elements?

Comment: The itemList value is independent from the Command: the values can come from every object in a scope visible to the page. That's the reason why you need to specify the object and the list attribute

Comment: Ah, good to know.  I appreciate all your help.  Everything is in good working order :)

Answer (score 2):

Usualy I am doing it with spring tag like this :

```
<springform:select path="myObjectList" id="selected_company">
    <springform:option value="0" label="--- Select One ---"></springform:option>
    <springform:options items="${myObjectList}" itemValue="company" itemLabel="company"></springform:options>
</springform:select>
```

don't forget including the namespace declaration :
xmlns:springform="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"