# Getting null values from checkboxes

Tags: spring-mvc, arraylist, data-binding, jstl

I am working on a simple Spring MVC project. I am having trouble getting values from checkboxes. What I mean is when a user checks 2 boxes out of 3, all 3 are binded to a list with non-checked values as null. That's wrong. I just want values that are checked. Those that didn't get checked should not come to list at all. 
This is a snippet of my code:
POJO:

```
public class Student{
private List<StudentCourses> sc;
//getters and setters
}

public class StudentCourses{
private int courseID;
private String courseName;
private Character grade;
private String semesterID;
//getters and setters
}
```

This is what I send from my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/selectclasses", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String selectClasses(Model m) {
Student s = new Student();
List<StudentCourses> coursesList = new ArrayList<StudentCourses>();
coursesList.add(new StudentCourses("Eng 101", '-', "SP 16"));
coursesList.add(new StudentCourses("Math 140", '-', "SP 16"));
coursesList.add(new StudentCourses("CS 442", '-', "SP 16"));
m.addAttribute("coursesList", coursesList);
m.addAttribute("student", s);
return "selectclasses";
}
```

This is what I have in my selectclasses.jsp:

```
    <form:form modelAttribute="student" method="post" action="/success">
        <table>
            <c:forEach items="${coursesList}" var="r" begin="0" varStatus="status">
                <form:checkbox path="sc[${status.index }].courseName" value="${r.courseName}" label="${r.courseName}" />
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form:form>
```

I don't know why null is passed to the "sc.courseName" when it's not checked. What am I doing wrong? Or is there a work around it?

Please help 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Solution!

I found two ways to solve it. This is the solution using Spring tags:

```
<form:checkboxes path="sc" items="${coursesList}" itemValue="courseName" itemLabel="courseName" />
```

In the above code, itemValue and itemLabel is the main thing! **itemValue and itemLabel simply refer to bean properties of an object inside items attribute (items="${coursesList}"). In a nutshell, if you need to use a List of your Custom Beans as the items attribute you need to use also the itemValue and itemLabel attributes.** This bold part of paragraph is taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15529281/4828463 by @Carlos Gavidia

And now the solution using JSTL core tags:

```
    <c:forEach items="${coursesList}" var="courses">
        <tr>
            <td><form:checkbox path="sc" value="${courses.courseName}" label="${courses.courseName}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

Again the `value` and `label` attributes are important.

Answer (score 0):

simply writer

```
<input type="checkbox" value="${r.courseName}" id="id"name="name"/>
```

in controller class get the values using

```
String []values=request.getParameterValues(pass the id);
```

simple you get the selected values

Comment: Sorry mate I just saw your answer. I haven't tested your solution but I myself have found a solution. Also, you are using html tags. I cannot use html tags. I can use either JSTL core tags or Spring tags. The solution, which I am about to post, uses both JSTL core tags and Spring tags. Thanks for trying to answer my question though. Much appreciated.